# What are valid PixelFormats on different Android devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, pixelformat

When setting the PixelFormat on an Android GLSurfaceView, such as:

```
glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Is there any limitation on particular PixelFormats for particular devices, or are all PixelFormats supposed to work on all devices?

If there are limitations, then how can I find out which PixelFormats are supported on the current device?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any documentation explicitly outlining the level of device support for any given `PixelFormat`. But if you look at the [documentation for PixelFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html) you'll see an **Added in API level *...*** tag to the right.

I believe this means their support is based on the Android API level running on the device, not the device itself.

For example `RGBA_8888` was `Added in API level 1` so that's 100% available. But `RGBA_F16` was `Added in API level 26`, so only those devices running `Android 8.0.0 (Oreo)` or higher will support it.